# Colormapped image required when converting .tif to .png with ImageMagick

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, imagemagick

As the title says when running the command:

```bsh
convert -depth 32 ./heightmap.tif ./heightmap.png
```

I recieve the error:

```bsh
convert: colormapped image required `./heightmap.tif' @ error/quantum-import.c/ImportIndexQuantum/3034
```

From looking around I can only find this error in the code to print it out, has anyone come across is before? No one else has seemed to have any issue converting from `.tif`, and if they have it's because of delegate issues which I have already resolved.

This is on Windows Subsystem for Linux, running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and a fresh install of ImageMagick:

```bsh
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-52 Q16 x86_64 2020-12-19 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
```